# ruby 2.6.1, rails で `You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile` がでます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

- ruby 2.6.1
- rail 5.2.2
- bundler 2.0.1

で rails をインストールしていたところ、 `bundle install` は実行できるにもかかわらず、ありとあらゆる rails コマンドが

> You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.

とエラーを出力します。これはどうやったら対処できますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

これが原因の様子です。

- https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/15582

ruby 自体が bundler を内部に含むようになり、それが、 bundler 1.17.2 のバージョンを固定で利用するために生じているバグの様子です。

- 2.6(.1?) から発生しているバグであること
- すでに closed でそのうち patch リリースされるであろうこと

を考えると、 2.6.2 がリリースされるまでは、 ruby 2.5.3 を利用する方が良さそうです。

#### FWIW

2.6.1 をどうしても使いたい場合は、以下の対応でどうにかなるっぽいです。

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54189640/3090068